# How can I pre populate sqlite database?

Tags: database, sqlite

I need to pre populate SQLite database with random data (letters,numbers and @).
How can i do this?

Comment: How do you use SQLite? What programming language or shell?

Comment: Manually insert data in the database using SQLite Browser & then follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/using-already-created-database-with-android/9109728#9109728

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the [`INSERT` statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).

Comment: Potentially in combination with a `SELECT` statement to find out if it has already been populated.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite contains a [random() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).

You can use it to generate the records you want to insert.

For example :

```
insert into sampleTable (colint, colchar) values (RANDOM(), CAST(RANDOM() AS TEXT))
```

In real cases, you should probably also combine it with `min` and `max` in order to produce values accorded to your need.